# How to configure gulp's dependencies to prevent running 'clean' each time watch is triggered

Tags: javascript, gulp

With a simple build structure as follow (where `{...}` stand for non relevant callbacks):

```
gulp.task('clean', {...}); //task I want to run once before the first build
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], {...}); //task I want to run at each change

gulp.task('watch, ['build'], function() {
  gulp.watch('./', ['build']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Each time the 'watch' is triggered, the 'clean' task is run before the 'build' task... I would like to avoid to re-run 'clean' each time.

I tried for a while to find a dependencies structure that would allow that or a tool I would have missed but I didn't find any solutions that didn't seems overly complicated.

What would be the best way to deal with this ?

Comment: Well, can you run it once before running the 'watch' task?

Comment: Is there a way to manually run a task in another task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 2 different tasks.

```
gulp.task('build-with-clean', ['clean'], {...});
gulp.task('build-to-watch', {...});
gulp.task('watch', ['build-to-watch'], function() {
  gulp.watch('./', ['build-to-watch']);
});
```